# Xcode 12.4 build successful but getting NSCocoaErrorDomain Code: 257 You don’t have permission

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode12

I'm trying to build my react native project using the xcode. Project gets build successfully but its not running on the simulator or on the device.

Whenever i'm trying to build the app i get the below error:

```
Details
```

### The file “myapp” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.
Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: 257
Failure Reason: You don’t have permission.
Recovery Suggestion: To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.
User Info: {
NSFilePath = "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-aylojruwzhsbrrbwomkiwefxqlxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app";
}

### The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 13
Failure Reason: Permission denied

System Information

macOS Version 10.15.7 (Build 19H512)
Xcode 12.4 (17801) (Build 12D4e)

I have tried to solve this by removing the DerivedData folder and even checking the permission of the folder. Currently all the files in this folder are set to my system user and staff and all the files have permission set to 755.

Also i tried changing the system privacy setting by giving full access to Xcode but still i'm facing the same issue.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: did you found any solution ? even i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. For me I had accidentally changed the `Executable file` property in `info.plist` rather than changing the `Bundle display name` property. Fixing this fixed the error for me.